# What is the umbrella term for ä, ö and ü and the little dots on them?

Tags: terminology, umlaut

In English, the sounds like *a, e, i, o* or *u* are called vowel sounds.
I want to know, whether *ä, ö,* and *ü* have certain names in German language and what the dots used to produce them are called.

Comment: Are you asking about the letters, the sounds or both?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Multiple questions, multiple answers:

> In English, the sounds like *a, e, i, o, u* are called vowel sounds.

Erm, technically true, but you’re forgetting *y*. And there are a lot more vowel sounds that just the five ‘standard’ ones. There are some twenty different vowel sounds in English if you include diphthongs (and there’s no real reason not to).

> I want to know, do these sounds like *ä, ö, ü* have certain names in German language?

Germans would consider them vowels just like the other five (*y* is a variant of either *ü* or *i*) and the diphthongs (*ei, au, eu, ui*) German language has. If there is, for any reason, a need to specify that you’re talking about and only about the three dotted ones, the terminology is *Umlaute*. If you’re just talking about a specific one, it’s *Ä*, *Ö* or *Ü*, just like they’re pronounced.

> what [are] the dots used to produce them […] called?

A.k.a. the question in the title. These dots, usually called *trema* (or [*diaeresis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))) in English, are called *Umlaut* in German (yes, this is the same word as above for the vowels themselves) *if and only if* they are used to signify *Umlaute*.

If you’re talking about a word like *naïve*, or the Albanian letter *ë*, the only correct terminology is *I/E mit Trema*. This also occurs in generic German names (*Hoëcker*) and old-fashioned spelling (*Alzeÿ*). Note that German generally prefers the word *Trema* where *Umlaut* is not applicable, while English prefers *diaeresis* for the *naïve*-case and *trema* only for distinct non-umlaut letters. (In the *Alzeÿ*-case, *Diärese* would be outright wrong.)

The word *Trema* can also be used in the case of umlauts. So it’s perfectly acceptable to say *A mit Trema*.

Colloquially, the dots also have a variety of other names derived from their shape: *Punkte, Doppelpunkt, Pünktchen, Striche, Stricherl, Strichelchen* and more. Note again, that any *Strich*-type variant is only applicable, if you’re talking about *ä/ö/ü*. *Ï* and *ë* would only get names that derive from *Punkt* in some way.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

In case you’re interested: *Trema* originates from Ancient Greek and is a name based solely on the shape of the diacritic.

*Umlaut*, as you might have guessed, stems from the German word which means *changed sound*.

*Diaeresis* is also Greek, meaning *division* or *separation*. It is only truly appropriate in cases where the trema shows that two letters are to be pronounced distinctly.

---

[1] This is due to the origin of the tremata. For the three common German letters, they derived from a superscripted *e*, which in blackletter and even more in [*Kurrent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) handwriting resembles a pair of vertical lines. Eventually, the *e* got reduced to the vertical lines which got further reduced in typesetting to a pair of dots. For diaeresis cases, the dots did not derive from lines but were introduced as dots originally.

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: @Jan You forgot to mention that vowel sounds are *Vokale* in German and diphtong can be called *Doppellaut* (älter) oder *Zweilaut*. But that is really all you left to us :).

Comment: I disagree with the notion that _Umlaut_ is a synonym of _Trema_. You don’t call the dots “Umlaut”.

Comment: I've never heard anybody name the dots umlaut aswell. Umlaut is ä/ü/ö, the dots are called "Pünktchen", "Strichelchen" or simply "Punkte" (dots).

Comment: I agree with @chirlu and @Alex; I cannot imagine anyone saying "Ich füge einen Umlaut zum *a* hinzu, um es zu einem *ä* zu machen." Während umgangssprachlich "Punkte", "Pünktchen" etc. gebräuchlich sind, scheint zumindest Wikipedia zwischen [Trema](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema) und [Diärese](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di%C3%A4rese) im Deutschen genau so zu unterscheiden, wie du es im letzten Satz auf Englisch tust ("Diaeresis is also Greek, meaning division or separation. It is only truly appropriate in cases where the trema shows that two letters are to be pronounced distinctly.").

Comment: @chirlu I added the name *Trema* for the *Umlaut* case which is indeed true and was overlooked before. I have, however, heard people say *A mit Umlaut*.

Comment: @Alex added colloquial names. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Jan: "I have, however, heard people say A mit Umlaut." - Are you sure you are not mixing up languages? I have heard many people say the very similar "A with umlaut" in English and usually perceived it as a tell-tale sign that they don't know the original meaning of "Umlaut" as it would be used in German. But then, maybe "Umlaut" is just not used like that in my region.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I am. It was my mother. She's very German. Sorry ^^' But I still agree that it's very rarely heard.

Comment: *technically true, but you’re forgetting* y – And *r* and *w* and probably some more, depending on your definition of *vowel.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Attempted to address that in the following sentence ;)

Comment: @ThorstenS. I just went through the text while looking for places that needed rewording due to the question’s edit. Turns out, there’s no reason for me to include the German terms for *diphthong*, because the question’s not about them. I’m not even saying that German can use the same word ;)

Comment: the dots are NOT called umlaut, umlaut is just the vowel.

Answer (score 16):

The result of the dots, so the letter with the dots on it, is an **Umlaut** – literally a “resounding” – of the vowel.

The dots themselves are commonly known as **ä/ö/ü-Striche** (or Strichelchen), depending on what word you have in mind. That’s what we, including the teachers, used in school. The term umlaut only came to my attention once I started having contact with English speakers who would learn German. But that might just be me.
The term *trema* however is widely … unknown. I'd recommend not using it.

Comment: _ä/ö/ü-Punkte_ and _ä/ö/ü-Pünktchen_ as well.

Comment: I learned about the word "Umlaut" in elementary school, while learning to read and write (which included some info on "Selbstlaute, Mitlaute und Umlaute"); I don't think it's really that unknown. I agree that the word "Trema" is not as widely known, or rather, that  it is to some extent misinterpreted as meaning diaeresis, i.e. separate pronunciation of two letters, rather than the mere graphical modifier in the shape of two dots.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I believe Emanual wanted to say “the term umlaut *for the dots*”, not referring to *Umlaut* in general.

Comment: @chirlu... no, I actually meant the term :). I honestly did not really know what that was until I was 20 or so. I mean I kind of knew but not really. Maybe I was just ignoring it in school though.

Answer (score 6):

To be absolutely accurate, “Umlaut” is a technical term for the phonological/historical process which transforms - for example - /u/ to /y/. This is the only meaning recognised in the standard dictionaries (DWB, DWDS, Duden). The two dots on top of some letters are properly called “Pünktchen”.

Compare this: http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Umlaut
and this: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Umlaut

Answer (score 3):

In English the sign is called *umlaut*. In German is *Umlaut* or *Trema*.

> ö

is then

> o mit Umlaut.

Similar for the other two vowels.

Comment: I disagree. As I've mentioned in another comment, I cannot imagine anyone say "Ich füge einen Umlaut zu *o* hinzu, um es zu einem *ö* zu machen." The "Umlaut" is the whole thing, the letter with the dots, not just the dots. Is that possibly a regional difference, though (I'm from South-Western Germany)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Just because it is correct, does not mean it is used; I'll agree with you on that one. If anybody would use it, it's people in a semi-professional environment, i.e. typesetters, linguists, not necessarily school teachers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Maybe. But this is an answer to the original, first question of the OP, thereafter edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you see them on the names of heavy metal bands (*Motörhead*) who only want to look exotic, these are called *rock dots*.

Edit:
In German these are called *Heavy-Metal-Umlaut* according to Wikipedia.
Also *rock dots* can be written as *röck döts*.

Comment: Are they called so *in German*?

Comment: Actually, I think there's more behind it. German is associated with harshness, militarism, violent-sounding language, and the first uses of rock dots were on letters that would make sense to use that way in German (*ä, ö* and *ü*). But it has since left that territory and gone to completely arbitrary letters (n with trema, anyone?).

Comment: FWIW, using these produces the opposite of the intended effect for me as a german. "Moteurhead" just sounds cute or dumb, not hard and cool.

Answer (score -1):

[Diakritische Zeichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diakritisches_Zeichen) is a term covering trema, any kind of accent, cedille and other letter "ornamentation" without the letter itself.

Comment: True, but doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @chirlu I can't find a hint in the original question, how generic a term the OP was looking for; I find a downvote of a correct and at least supplemental [if not even useful] answer somewhat harsh.