# Pronunciation of the surname Ruhle

Tags: pronunciation, person-names

I live in Australia and I had a big family gathering over the weekend. We know that our ancestors moved to Australia from Germany in the late 1800s.

There was a big argument over how to properly pronounce our surname *Ruhle*. Most people say it like the English word *rule* but some insisted that it is pronounced like the English word *really*.

I was wondering if anyone would know how to pronounce the name properly

**EDIT** - The name was originally spelt *Rühle*.

**EDIT** - I found a pronunciation website with *Rühle* pronounced: [http://forvo.com/word/Rühle/](http://forvo.com/word/R%C3%BChle/)

Comment: Note that the 'h' makes the preceding vowel "long" and "stressed", irrelevant of it being 'u' or 'ü'.

Comment: The pronounciation is ok-ish, she just puts an almost-'ö' at the end where I'd put a 'schwa' with a quite distinct tendency to a clear 'e'.

Comment: This is fascinating. I was harshly corrected about 25 years ago for introducing myself as Duane Ruhle (rule). The individual who was adamant I was wrong pronounced Ruhle as really. Since then I have learnt about the umlaut above the U and its pronunciation and that the H makes it an even longer sound. My thoughts on the difference in pronunciation is that around the 2nd WW many descendants of Germans were persecuted and ostracized here in Australia. In fact many town names and street names with German origins were changed. My theory is that some changed spelling or pronunciations to escape thi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the original form of the name was *Ruhle* without an umlaut, its German pronunciation would be very similar to the word *ruler* in [non-rhotic accents of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English) (which include Australian English), i.e. with two syllables, unlike *rule*. In the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (IPA), the pronunciation would be represented as [ˈruːlə].

If, on the other hand, it was *Rühle*, then it would be more like an English *reeler*; however, the first vowel would be spoken with rounded lips, a sound that doesn’t exist in English: [ˈryːlə]. This version is of course close to *really*.

In both cases, there are additional minor differences between English and German in the way the *r* and *l* sounds are pronounced.

The spelling *Ruhlë* is unlikely because German really only uses *ä*, *ö*, *ü*. Of course, nothing is impossible with names; quite likely, if it indeed was *Ruhlë*, that would have been pronounced the same as a plain *Ruhle*.

Comment: And let me add that "Rühle" is pretty common in SW Germany (Swabia).

Comment: A trema on the letter e (ë) are not a standard feature of German language. A trema is not an Umlaut! (Umlauts are only ä, ö and ü). But a trema can appear in rare cases on i or e (ï, ë) to mark that the letter with the trema is not part of a diphthong.

Comment: Without trema the name of the German commedian *Bernd Hoëcker* would be pronounced like *Höcker* (oe=ö in German), and the group of islands *Alëuten* would be pronounced like *Aloiten*, because *eu* is normally spoken as *oi*. But the e in *Ruhle* does not stand next to another vovel with wich it could be interpreted as part of a diphthong. So there can not be a trema on this e.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: The word _trema_ is rarely used in English. Unlike the German word from which it is derived, the English word _umlaut_ does mean ‘the two dots on a letter such as ä’. Some people distinguish it from a _diaeresis_ (for them, _umlaut_ is the dots indicating a sound change and _diaresis_ the dots indicating a separate syllable), but others don’t. – Wikipedia [claims](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Ho%C3%ABcker#Name) that the diaeresis in _Bernhard Hoëcker_ is not part of his official name.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast http://german.stackexchange.com/a/23235/15318

Comment: @chirlu, I don't see the point in your comment. If a word is rarely used, then what, we have to ignore it? _Umlaut_ and _diaeresis_ are also distinguished in English, since the distinction is important to understand what it means for the pronunciation. Helmut didn't claim that _Bernhard Hoëcker_  is the official name (but this form of the name appears obviously), so what do you want to say with this remark?

Comment: @chirlu names or not, the point still stands — German doesn't generally use ë or ï, and when it does, it isn't umlaut (instead, it's for purposes of separating vowel sounds, as in naïve or the archaic spellings coöperation or reëducation). So Ruhlë isn't a reasonable candidate here. And when *discussing German* I think it's reasonable to call umlaut umlaut, and call not-umlaut not-umlaut.

Comment: @hobbs: Would you mind looking *at my post* and pointing out where I have said 1. that German does generally use _ë_ or _ï_, 2. that when it does so, it is umlaut in the linguistic meaning, 3. that _Ruhlë_ is a reasonable candidate here? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The names *Rühle/Ruehle* do seem to be a bit more common in Germany than *Ruhle*. On the other hand, if your ancestors spelled their surname *Ruehle* there was no reason to change it, and if they spelled it *Rühle* they would most likely have transcribed this as *Ruehle* right upon entering the country. (PS: But as hobbs pointed out in a comment, it’s quite possible that someone else with no knowledge of German transcribed the name from German passports.)

For now, let’s assume the original name to be *Ruhle* without the umlaut.

What you want is probably not an accent-free German pronunciation but an English one that is conscious of the name’s origin. That would be like the English word *rule*, but with the final *e* pronounced (without giving it any stress). Sort of like pronouncing the words *rule export*, stressing the first word, and stopping right before the *x*.

Now if the original name was *Rühle*, after all, then only the quality of the *u* sound would be different. Since most native English speakers can neither produce a proper *ü* sound nor hear the difference, you needn’t worry about this. But if you can speak French, it’s almost exactly the same as the French *u* sound, as for example in *sûrement*.

By the way, *ë* only appears in German in the same way and for the same reasons that some people write the English word *co-operation* as *coöperation*. (The only exception is Luxembourgish, which might be called a national language that is also a German dialect. In Luxembourgish orthography, *ë* denotes a sound somewhere between *e* and *ö* and is transcribed as *eo* when the letter is not available. But this is not relevant to your name as it has no common variant of this kind.) It is conceivable that upon entering Australia your ancestors might have changed the spelling of their name to *Ruhlë* in order to indicate that the last syllable should be pronounced. But even this doesn’t seem very likely.

Comment: I don't know about Australia, but immigrants to the United States historically were at the mercy of immigration officials for the recording of their names, and a lot was often lost in the process. Especially when the immigrant couldn't spell their name to begin with it might be changed radically, but even if they were literate an umlaut could be lost because "we don't have those here" and no one thought to use the ue-convention. Either is certainly plausible in my opinion.

Comment: @hobbs: Thanks for the correction. As a European I didn't think of that possibility.

Comment: *the English word rule, but with the final e pronounced* makes no sense.

Comment: @Walter: If this sentence in the explanation doesn't help you, you are free to ignore it and concentrate on the next one. But most native English speakers are somewhat used to the idea of pronouncing word-final *e* from pronouncing French and Spanish words such as *paso doble*, and may even be able to do it without undue stress and without turning it into a diphthong. (In Middle English, word final *e* was still pronounced this way in most English words, at least optionally.)